# By using set identities, prove that for all sets A and B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$(A − B) \cap (A \cap B) = \varnothing$

how can this be solved

Comment: There are two problems with providing either an answer or a hint-answer: [1] You haven't shown any work and it is difficult to conjure a hint that is not *comprehensive* [2] Independently, any response is redundant, in light of the comment of player3236.

Answer (score -1):

$A \cap B \subseteq B$ but $B$ is disjoint from $A-B$.